# Angular Default Currency Pipe not working along with amount

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, currency-pipe

I have a problem with the already built in CurrencyPipe from Angular.
I have tried with  following

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-7"><p>Delivery fee </p></div>
  <div class="col-5 text-right">
    <p>{{cartService.getItems().length > 0 ? 10 : 0 | currency:'INR':'symbol-narrow'}} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It display only the value not displaying currency along with the amount.

Output:

```
10
```

Expected output

```
₹10
```

I am also using angular pipe for displaying another amount. which is working perfectly along with amount.

```
<div class="row pad-top20">
  <div class="col-7"><p><strong>Total</strong></p></div>
  <div class="col-5 text-right">
    <p><strong>{{calculateGrandTotal() | currency:'INR':'symbol-narrow'}}</strong></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output :

₹22,180.00

What is the difference between these two angular currency pipes ?
Thanks!!

Comment: make the cart length 0, and execute the else logic in ternary. you will get the currency with 0 then I am sure. Just check and let me know. I guess you have to put pipe for both conditions. If this works let me know I will answer it then.

Comment: @WahabShah Thank you. I have added currency pipe for both condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add `(` and `)` before currency pipe in code. Like this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-7"><p>Delivery fee </p></div>
  <div class="col-5 text-right">
    <p>{{(cartService.getItems().length > 0 ? 10 : 0) | currency:'INR':'symbol-narrow'}} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be really appreciated if you can accept this solution ;)

Comment: thanks. it's working.  i have added  currency pipe for both condition for resolving the same. your answer is much  more easy.

Answer (score 0):

I have added currency pipe for both condition.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-7"><p>Delivery fee </p></div>
      <div class="col-5 text-right">
        <p>{{cartService.getItems().length > 0 ? (10| currency:'INR':'symbol-narrow') : (0 | currency:'INR':'symbol-narrow')}} </p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is horrible you shouldn't have to do this. wrapping with () should work like pynode suggested. worst case make a getter or a func that returns 0 or 10